# MYSQL LEFT JOIN add condition on other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

```
select principalTable.X, secondTable.ART, secondTable.DETT
from 
(principalTable

left join thirdTable
on on principalTable.X = thirdTable.X

left join secondTable
on principalTable.ART = secondTable.ART and thirdTable.ID = secondTable.ID
)
```

I've got `3` tables that show some cross data from this query, I need a condition to select only the data from the `secondtable` that had a common index with the `thirdtable`, else without the and condition there can be many incorrect results.
I've tried the same query with the `and` applied to `principalTable` and with that,this work. With the condition applied on the `thirdTable` it won't work.

Every advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show some sample data from the three tables and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following query.

```
select principalTable.X, secondTable.ART, secondTable.DETT 
form principalTable pt,secondTable st,thirdTable tt
where pt.X = tt.X AND pt.ART = st.ART AND st.ID = tt.ID
```